# React - обработка изменений и отправка данных на сервер

Tags: javascript, reactjs

При работе над проектом столкнулся над проблемой. В общем я получаю JSON данные по API и вывожу данные в таблицу. В таблице есть поля которые можно изменить (числовые).

Нужно сделать так, чтобы после ввода в input данных, информация отправлялась на Сервер по API. Там все обрабатывается, подсчитываются некоторые данные и потом мне нужно снова забрать все данные из сервера.

Конечно, есть вариант onChange для input, но не хочется при каждом вводе какого-то одного символа отправлять на сервер запрос и получать снова кучу данных, это замедлить работу (чел ввел 5 символов - это 5 запросов и 5 ответов с достаточно большими данными).

Пример моего компонента:

```
class Table extends React.Component {
    handleOnChange(){ ... }
    render() {
        const data = this.props.data;
        return (
            <table>
                ...
                <tbody>
                    {data.map(item => (
                        <tr>
                            <td>{item.id}</td>
                            <td>
                                <input 
                                    type="text" 
                                    placeholder={item.count} 
                                    onChange={() => this.handleOnChange()}
                                />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    )}
                </tbody>
            </table>
        )
    }
}
```

Как сделать задумку? Пытался сделать новый компонент и обрабатывать там события и по setTimeout отправить данные, но не понял как, например, из **TableTr** вызвать функцию, которая **Table** и передать ей аргументы (значение input). Ref-ы использовать не получится вроде, там много компонентов TableTr будет.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.5) в помощь. Функции { debounce, throttle }.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { debounce, throttle } from 'lodash'

class Table extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
        editingItem: {},
        data: [],
    }
}
delayedСall = debounce((value, item) => { // отложеный вызов на 500ms
    //this.fetchApi() !!!!
    console.log(value)
}, 500)
delayedCutСall = throttle((value, item) => { // вызов раз в 500ms
    //this.fetchApi() !!!!
    console.log(value)
}, 500)
handleOnFocus = (item) => {
    this.setState({ editingItem: item })
}
handleOnChange = (e, item) => {
    const { value } = e.target
    this.setState({ editingItem: { ...this.state.editingItem, value } })
    this.delayedСall(value, item)
    this.delayedCutСall(value, item)
}
handleOnBlur = () => {
    this.setState({
        data: this.state.data.map(i => (i.id === 
        this.state.editingItem.id ? this.state.editingItem : i)),
    })
}
render() {
    const { data, editingItem } = this.state;
    return (
        <table>
            <tbody>
                {data.map(item => (
                    <tr key={item.id}>
                        <td>{item.id}</td>
                        <td>
                            <input
                                type="text"
                                placeholder={item.count}
                                value={item.id === editingItem.id ? editingItem.value : item.value}
                                onChange={(e) => { this.handleOnChange(e, item) }}
                                onFocus={(e) => { this.handleOnFocus(item) }}
                                onBlur={this.handleOnBlur}
                            />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                ))}
            </tbody>
        </table>
    )
}
}
```

[Полезный пример сходу](https://webdevkin.ru/posts/frontend/kak-ispolzovat-throttle-i-debounce)
*Примечание*: Если необходимо производительно - input следовалобы вынести в отдельный компонент, что бы вовремя onChange не рендерить всю таблицу.

Если используете Redux, рекомендую обрать внимения на [Redux-Saga](https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/recipes/) где эти функции также реализованы